# mysql query counts nothing

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I have a mysql table holding a few records as shown in the picture bellow!

[image: date_time field has datetime datatype]

I have the following query to count the number of records (number of records for sr13, r4 and huawei) in the specified time range.

```
$date1 = "2012-01-02 03";
$date2 = "2014-12-30 24";
$counter_result = $this->db->query("select count(sr13) as count_sr13, count(r4) as count_r4, count(huawei) as count_huawei from cdrcount where date_time BETWEEN '$date1%' and '$date2%' ");
```

the query returns the value of the three fields as 0.
is there any thing wrong with the query?

Comment: Are you really trying to compare `date_time` against two strings with the wildcard placeholder `%` in the end?

Comment: Yes this is the query I am running just now!

Comment: The query probably yields zero rows, which is why they're all `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare date properly, you should use these full values:

```
$date1 = "2012-01-02 03:00:00";
$date2 = "2014-12-30 23:59:59";
```

And drop the `%` from the query:

```
$counter_result = $this->db->query("select count(sr13) as count_sr13, count(r4) as count_r4, count(huawei) as count_huawei 
    from cdrcount 
    where date_time BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `date_time` was implicitly cast to string because your values in `BETWEEN` contains `%`. Thus, it compares date in string data type with values that contains `%` and obviously no records were matched, try removing it,

```
select  count(sr13) as count_sr13, 
        count(r4) as count_r4, 
        count(huawei) as count_huawei 
from    cdrcount 
where   date_time BETWEEN '$date1' and '$date2'
```

and your date should be formatted into a valid date eg, `2012-01-02 03:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

Try `time_to_sec` function

```
select count(sr13) as count_sr13, count(r4) as
count_r4, count(huawei) as count_huawei from cdrcount 
where time_to_sec(date_time) 
BETWEEN time_to_sec('date1') and time_to_sec('date2');
```